# Decrypting HTTPS traffic with a proxy

Tags: c, encryption, https, proxy, openssl

I am implementing a Web proxy (in C), with the end goal of implementing some simple caching and adblocking. Currently, the proxy supports normal HTTP sites, and also supports HTTPS sites by implementing tunneling with HTTP CONNECT. The proxy works great running from localhost and configured with my browser.

Despite all of this, I'll never be able to implement my desired features as long as the proxy can not decrypt HTTPS traffic. The essence of my question is: what general steps do I need to take to be able to decrypt this traffic and implement what I would like? I've been researching this, and there seems to be a good amount of information on existing proxies that are capable of this, such as [Squid](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice).

Currently, my server uses select() and keeps all client ids in an fd_set. When a CONNECT request is made, it makes a TCP connection to the specified host, and places the file descriptor of both the client and the host into the fd_set. It also places the tuple of fd's into a list, and the list is scanned whenever more data is ready from select() to see if data is coming from an existing tunnel. The data is then read and forwarded blindly. I am struggling to see how to intercept this data at all, due to the nature of the CONNECT verb requiring opening a simple TCP socket to the desired host, and then "staying out of it" while the client and host set up their own SSL sockets. I am simply asking for the right direction for how I can go about using the proxy as a MITM attacker in order to read and manipulate the data coming in.

As a brief aside, this project is solely for my own use, so no security or advanced functionality is needed. I just need it to work for one browser, and I am happy to get any warnings from the browser if certificate-spoofing is the best approach.

Comment: Why do you think you need to implement your own proxy instead of just using squid?

Comment: This is a project I'm doing for my own learning benefit. I agree that if I just wanted a functioning proxy I'd just use Squid or something written by someone competent.

Comment: To decrypt HTTPS traffic use libssl.

Comment: In general you cannot do this as TLS/SSL has protections against this essentially MITM attack. If you can get your MITM certificate to be trusted by clients then you might succeed.

Answer (score 0):

> proxy can not decrypt HTTPS traffic

You are trying to mount a man-in-the-middle attack. SSL is designed to prevent that. But - there is a weak point - a list of trusted certificate authorities.

> I am simply asking for the right direction for how I can go about using the proxy as a MITM attacker in order to read and manipulate the data coming in.

You can get  inspiration from Fiddler. The Fiddler has its own CA certificate (certification authority) and once you add this CA certificate as trusted, then Fiddler generates server certificates for each connection you use on the fly.

It comes with serious security consideration, your browser will trust any site. I've even seen using the Fiddler core inside a malware, so be careful